# Text Search in Sortable R

Tags: r, shiny, jquery-ui-sortable, sortablejs

Is there any way to include text search option in `add_rank_list` from `sortable` package in R? Image below, for example we have a long list of items, any way we can include a text search that can help to search one of the item from the list?

Has searched SortableJS in https://sortablejs.github.io/Sortable/, but no success